# Double while loop for flushing data before a switch statement

Tags: c

I need to write a script for the user to enter a score between 0 and 10, flush the bad input out, if user inputs it and then using a switch statement, tell a user what grade did he/she got.

Here is my script:

```
         ...
int main()
{
int input;            // input from user

printf("Enter the number between 0 and 10 and I will tell you your grade!");

while ((input=scanf("Your input:", &input) != EOF))
{
    if (input < 0 || input > 10) //input is invalid
    {   
        printf("Sorry, invalid character data.");

        while (getchar() !='\n')
        {   
            printf("Your input must be from 0 to 10.", input);
            scanf("%d", &input); //This part looks very bad for me
        }
    }

    else
        switch (input)
        {                       
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                printf("Your grade is F. \n");
                break;  
            case 6:
                printf("Your grade is D. \n");
                break;
          ...
```

I got this far with my homework, and here are some "leftover" problems I can't fight with.

1) Whenever user submits anything after enter, it goes into infinite loop and prints **Your grade is F.**, even when case = 6 for example.

2) I used **break;** at the end of each case. It looks like they don't work(?)

3) It looks like the problem in the second line in the second loop

```
scanf("%d", &input); //This part looks very bad for me
```

but then I guess the scripts accepts it as true since the else statements that includes switch begins to work, because otherwise it wouldn't print **Your grade is F.**

Comment: You might want to read the documentation for `scanf()`.

Comment: This line `input=scanf("Your input:", &input)` is definitely wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. Have a look at what **flush_stream** is doing when we have invalid data...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void flush_stream();

void flush_stream() {
  char c;
  do {
    c = getchar();
  }
  while (!isdigit(c) && c != '\n');
  ungetc(c, stdin);
}

int main(void) {
  const char *prompt = "Input please: ";
  int input;            // input from user
  printf("Enter the number between 0 and 10 and I will tell you your grade!\n");
  while(1) {
    printf("%s", prompt);
    int ret = scanf("%d", &input);
    if(ret == 0) {
      printf("Sorry, invalid character data, your input must be from 0 to 10.\n");
      flush_stream();
      continue;
    }   
    if(ret > 0) {
      if (input < 0 || input > 10) {   
        printf("Sorry, invalid character data, your input must be from 0 to 10.\n");
        flush_stream();
        continue;
      }   

      switch (input) {                            
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
          printf("Your grade is F. \n");
          break;  
        case 6:
          printf("Your grade is D. \n");
          break;
      }   
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks awesome! I will remake mine looking at your code.

Answer (score -2):

It seems you are using `scanf` and `printf` wrong.

To input a number:

```
scanf("%d", &input);
```

To output a number:

```
printf("%d\n", input);
```

And in you while loop, when the input is illegal, why not just `continue` to the next loop?

```
while (true) {
    printf("input your grade here: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &input) == EOF) {
        break;
    }
    if (input < 0 || input > 10) {
        printf("your input is illegal.\n");
        continue;
    }
    switch (input) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please re-read the manual for `scanf` - If you do not enter a number - what happens in this code?